# SSIS error could not find "sgen.exe" in Window Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, window

I'm Working With SQL Server and SSIS

In my package has Script task to call Web Service
Package are run correctly in my laptop

But when I Deploy package on Server (Visual Studio not installed) 
I get this error  when run

```
Date        9/26/2016 8:16:22 PM
Log     Job History (TestCallws)

Step ID     1
Server      CRM2016
Job Name        TestCallws
Step Name       test
Duration        00:00:02
Sql Severity    0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed    
Operator Net sent   
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted   0

Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  
Version 12.0.2000.8 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    
Started:  8:16:22 PM  
Error: 2016-09-26 20:16:24.45     
Code: 0x00000005     
Source: Script Task Script Task     
Description: Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. 
Open the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors.  
End Error  

Error: 2016-09-26 20:16:24.45     
Code: 0x00000005     
Source: Script Task Script Task     
Description: MSB3086 - Task could not find "sgen.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". 
Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets, 2769, 5  
End Error  

Error: 2016-09-26 20:16:24.47     
Code: 0x00000005     
Source: Script Task Script Task     
Description: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.  
End Error  

Error: 2016-09-26 20:16:24.50     
Code: 0x00000004     
Source: Script Task      
Description: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.  
End Error  

Error: 2016-09-26 20:16:24.50     
Code: 0xC0024107     
Source: Script Task      
Description: There were errors during task validation.  
End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  

Started:  8:16:22 PM  
Finished: 8:16:24 PM  Elapsed:  1.703 seconds.  
The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

Any one can help me to solve this problem

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to no .Net SDK installed on your destination server. It is needed for your web task, to generate serialization assembly.
You can fix it in a number of ways - install .Net 4.0 SDK on the target server.
Alternative - disable **Generate Serialization Assembly** option. To do this - open your *Script task*, go to edit script code, then select project and open its properties (with context menu). On *Build* page - select *Generate serialization assembly* and pick **Off**. Then save your code and project before you leave code editor.

Comment: have the same error but disabling Generate Serialization Assembly option didn't work for me